# IBM Watson Assistant Web Chat not keeping session state when navigating through my website

Tags: html, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to set up IBM Watson Assistant Web Chat and from the documentation, it seems pretty simple (just do the config and copy and paste the embed code) https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat

However, I have found that when I paste this onto my website, navigating to a different page or reloading will just refresh the session. This is not what I want as I want the session to continue off from where it was in the chat (and for all this to be displayed in the window). I have tried looking through the detailed documentation as well, but there doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for: https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=

I have also tried passing in the userid but still on navigation the chat refreshes.

Does anyone know if there's a way to solve this? I really need a solution since the same problem occurs on the live chat integration I have set up with salesforce.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: To preserve a session across web pages you would need cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A feature update to support session history is coming soon.

Comment: You may find that you will need to extend the IBM standard Web Chat client, to support the additional elements you require. For example the type of Watson Assistant service level will determine the length of time the session is retained by IBM before it gets expired. You may thus need to keep a copy yourself, via a database. 
To extend the IBM Web Chat Client is well documented within the developer documentation. https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=

Comment: @Dudi Hey, thanks for the response. Do you have an idea of roughly when the update is coming?

Comment: @BasilWoods sorry can't comment on it till its there, company regulations

Comment: its available for sometime now